# Basis for Polynomial Space

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

Let $V = \mathcal P_2$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $2$ with real coefficients, and let $W$ be the subset of polynomials $p(x)$ in $\mathcal P_2$ such that

$$\int_{-2}^0p(x)\,dx =4 \int_{0}^2p(x)\,dx.$$

Find a basis for $W$, and compute $\dim W.$

Plugging in $a+bx+cx^2$ and solving for both integrals gives me the equation $$8a+8b+\frac{32}3c = 2a-2b+\frac 83c,$$ which means I have the equation $$6a+10b+8c=0.$$ How do I write a basis of polynomials for this? And is the dimension $2$?

Comment: Assuming your earlier work is correct, letting $b=r$ and letting $c=s$ you have $\begin{cases} a = -10r/6-8s/6\\ b=r+0\\ c=0+s\end{cases}$.  Does that help?

Comment: That being said, your result seems suspect to me... shouldn't even polynomials satisfy this?

Comment: How would you find base from the last equation if you considered vector space $\Bbb R^3$ instead of $\mathcal P_2$?

Comment: @Ennar can I then just set up the augmented matrix (6  10  8) times (a  b  c ) = (0) and write the basis as {(-5/3,1,0),(-4/3,0,1)} ?

Comment: Yes. This is completely the same, with identification $(1,0,0)\mapsto 1, (0,1,0)\mapsto x, (0,0,1)\mapsto x^2$, i.e. $(a,b,c)\mapsto a+bx+cx^2$. Though, I think you made mistake in arriving to that equation.

Comment: I apologize, the question was typed wrong. The right side of the equation is multiplied by 4. You can look above I've made the change

Comment: John, compare $\{(-5/3,1,0),(-4/3,0,1)\}$ you got yourself with the answer by JMoravitz, considering my comment on identifying basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ with canonical base of $\Bbb R^3$. This is crucial for understanding how this works.

Comment: Aren't the vectors that I got the same? Just simplified?

Comment: Of course they are same (up to identification), that's the point. Hopefully now you understand how to do this on your own.

Answer (score 3):

**For the original post of $\int\limits_{-2}^0p(x)dx=\int\limits_{0}^2p(x)dx$**:

Suppose $p(x)=a+bx+cx^2$

Suppose that $\int\limits_{-2}^0 p(x)dx = \int\limits_0^2 p(x)dx$

Then we have:

$[ax+bx^2/2+cx^3/3]\mid_{-2}^0 = [ax+bx^2/2+cx^3/3]\mid_0^2$

$0-(-2a+2b-\frac{8}{3}~ c) = (2a+2b+\frac{8}{3}c)-0$

$2a-2b+\frac{8}{3}c=2a+2b+\frac{8}{3}c$

$b=0$

---

That is to say, we have learned that for a polynomial $a+bx+cx^2$ to be in this space, that we must have $b=0$ but there are otherwise no conditions on $a$ and $c$.

We could have guessed that this was the case without any effort simply by recognizing that it is in fact a subspace, recognizing that it is not the whole space so the dimension must be strictly less than three, and that both $p(x)=1$ and $p(x)=x^2$ live in the space and are linearly independent of one another.

---

---

For the edited problem:

Supposing that $p(x)=a+bx+cx^2$

Supposing that $\int\limits_{-2}^0p(x)dx=4\int\limits_{0}^2p(x)dx$

Then we have (*skipping some of the scratch work*)

$2a-2b+\frac{8}{3}c = 8a+8b+\frac{32}{3}c$

$6a=-10b-8c$, which you correctly arrived at.

Parameterizing the solutions then by letting $b=r$ and $c=s$, we have

$$\begin{cases}a=\frac{-5}{3}r+\frac{-4}{3}s\\b=r+0\\c=0+s\end{cases}$$ (*just as I wrote in my first comment*)

This implies that for $p(x)$ to be a polynomial satisfying the conditions, it must be of the form $r(-\frac{5}{3}+x)+s(-\frac{4}{3}+x^2)$, these two polynomials (*without the $r$ and the $s$*) act as our basis for the space, and the dimension (*i.e. number of basis elements required*) is two.

Comment: I apologize, the question was typed wrong. The right side of the equation is multiplied by 4. You can look above I've made the change. So the answer would be different